# Small request for information on the BOOL method

Tags: ios, boolean, parse-platform

Hello everyone I have a pretty dumb question but I want to make sure I fully understand this thing ...

Someone can ' explain in simple terms what they are doing this boolean method ?

```
- (BOOL) AssignedGoPointToPost : ( PFObject *) { GoPointAssigned
    for ( PFObject * goPoint in UpVoteCurrentUser ) {
        if ( [[[ goPoint objectForKey : @ " Oggetto_Votato "] objectId ] isEqualToString : GoPointAssigned.objectId ]) {
            return YES ;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

The query that accompanies the BOOL that interests me is this

```
- (void)  QueryForRelationGoPointWithPost {
    PFQuery queryForGoPointStatus * = [ PFQuery queryWithClassName : @ " goPoint "];
    [ queryForGoPointStatus whereKey : @ " AssegnatoDa " equalTo : [ PFUser currentUser ]] ;
    queryForGoPointStatus.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork ;
    [ queryForGoPointStatus findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock : ^ ( NSArray * objects, NSError * error ) {
        if (! error) {
            self.UpVoteCurrentUser = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc] init ] ;
            for ( PFObject * object in objects) {
                [ self.UpVoteCurrentUser addObject : object ] ;
            }
            [ self.FFTableView reloadData ] ;
        }
    } ] ;
}
```

In this part, in cellforRowIndexPath in TableView, I'm trying to change the image through the query ...

```
   if ([self AssignedGoPointToPost:ObjectPost]) {
            CellaIMG.MedalCount.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FFIMG_Medal_Blu"];
            CellaIMG.AddGoPoint.tag = indexPath.row;
            [CellaIMG.AddGoPoint addTarget:self action:@selector(DecrementGoPoint:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        } else {

            CellaIMG.MedalCount.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FFIMG_Medal"];
            CellaIMG.AddGoPoint.tag = indexPath.row;
            [CellaIMG.AddGoPoint addTarget:self action:@selector(AddGoPointAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        }
```

Let me explain ... Basically I'm trying to make a " Like Button " that when pressed saves its report in databrowser of parse.com and changes the image from a Medal Medal_Blu ...

The code that you see invokes two methods of action that I show below .. We say that the functions work well but the change of the data and the image is not simultaneous when you press the button "Like" ... Often even receives the command and does not save even update the data ... I can not understand where I'm wrong. I'm trying to build on the tutorials Parse.com

https://www.parse.com/tutorials/anypic # overview

Here I show you the two methods I use to save the action that the user click on the button "like"

```
- (Void) AddGoPointAction : (id) sender {
    FFCustomCellWithImage CellaIMG * = [ [ FFCustomCellWithImage alloc] init ] ;
    CellaIMG.MedalCount.image = [ UIImage imageNamed : @ " FFIMG_Medal_Blu "];
    
    PFObject SorgenteIncrementGoPointAction * = [ self.ArrayforPost objectAtIndex : [ sender tag ]] ;
    [ SorgenteIncrementGoPointAction incrementKey : FF_POST_GOPOINTPOST byAmount : [ NSNumber numberWithInt : +1 ]] ;
    [ SorgenteIncrementGoPointAction saveInBackground ] ;
    
    PFObject AssignGoPoint * = [ PFObject objectWithClassName : @ " goPoint "];
    [ AssignGoPoint setObject : @ " Post" Forkey : @ " type "];
    [ AssignGoPoint setObject : [ PFUser currentUser ] Forkey : @ " AssegnatoDa "];
    [ AssignGoPoint setObject : SorgenteIncrementGoPointAction Forkey : @ " Oggetto_Votato "];
    [ AssignGoPoint saveInBackground ] ;
    [ self.FFTableView reloadData ] ;
    [self QueryForRelationGoPointWithPost ] ;
    [self QueryForPost ] ;

    
}

- (Void) DecrementGoPoint : (id) sender {
    FFCustomCellWithImage CellaIMG * = [ [ FFCustomCellWithImage alloc] init ] ;
    CellaIMG.MedalCount.image = [ UIImage imageNamed : @ " FFIMG_Medal "];
    
    PFObject SorgenteDecrementGoPointAction * = [ self.ArrayforPost objectAtIndex : [ sender tag ]] ;
    [ SorgenteDecrementGoPointAction incrementKey : FF_POST_GOPOINTPOST byAmount : [ NSNumber numberWithInt : -1] ] ;
    [ SorgenteDecrementGoPointAction saveInBackground ] ;
    
    PFQuery DeleteGoPoint * = [ PFQuery queryWithClassName : @ " goPoint "];
    [ DeleteGoPoint whereKey : @ " Oggetto_Votato " equalTo : SorgenteDecrementGoPointAction ] ;
    [ DeleteGoPoint whereKey : @ " Type " equalTo : @ " Posts "];
    [ DeleteGoPoint whereKey : @ " AssegnatoDa " equalTo : [ PFUser currentUser ]] ;
    [ DeleteGoPoint findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock : ^ ( NSArray * RisultatoQueryDecrement , NSError * error ) {
        if (! error) {
            for ( PFObject * DeleteObject RisultatoQueryDecrement ) {
                [ DeleteObject deleteInBackground ] ;
            }
            [ self.FFTableView reloadData ] ;
            [self QueryForRelationGoPointWithPost ] ;
            [self QueryForPost ] ;
        }
    } ] ;


    
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Can you share what you are trying to do ? What you have done and what you are expecting from us to assist you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Someone can ' explain in simple terms what they are doing this boolean
>   method ?

```
- (BOOL) AssignedGoPointToPost : ( PFObject *) { GoPointAssigned
    for ( PFObject * goPoint in UpVoteCurrentUser ) {
        if ( [[[ goPoint objectForKey : @ " Oggetto_Votato "] objectId ] isEqualToString : GoPointAssigned.objectId ]) {
            return YES ;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

---

Infact this is not a boolean method, this is a method with return type BOOL(boolean).

There are some compiler errors too, first of all I would try to remove.

The method should look like as:

```
- (BOOL) AssignedGoPointToPost : ( PFObject *)GoPointAssigned {
    for ( PFObject * goPoint in UpVoteCurrentUser ) {
        if ( [[[ goPoint objectForKey : @ " Oggetto_Votato "] objectId ] isEqualToString : GoPointAssigned.objectId ]) {
            return YES ;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Now,

```
if ( [[[ goPoint objectForKey : @ " Oggetto_Votato "] objectId ] isEqualToString : GoPointAssigned.objectId ]) {
            return YES ;
```

In the above statement, goPoint is a dictionary where you are extracting some object based on key " Oggetto_Votato ". Then from the object you are accessing objectId which is supposed to be NSString. Then from this string you are comparing it with GoPointAssigned's objectId.

And if they match you are returning YES. This is inside the loop, hence the first match will be return YES and loop will terminate. If none are matched then loop with expire and NO will be returned.